# SQL XML Query with Name and Value Pairs

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have a string column in a SQL table that contains Parameters. For example:

```
<ParameterValues>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>Sub</Name>
        <Value>E23DD735-DCF4-4878-8810-EAC2594C58A4</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>OperatorId</Name>
        <Value>1001</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

Can anyone help me with a SQL Query to, for example, return the value from the Sub field where the OperatorId value is 1001. In this case, the answer would be 'E23DD735-DCF4-4878-8810-EAC2594C58A4'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to test it:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,YourXmlAsString NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
    ('<ParameterValues>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>Sub</Name>
        <Value>E23DD735-DCF4-4878-8810-EAC2594C58A4</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>OperatorId</Name>
        <Value>1001</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>');
```

A direct call to get exactly the one value your are looking for:

```
WITH Casted AS (SELECT ID,CAST(YourXmlAsString AS XML) AS TheXml FROM @tbl AS t)
SELECT TheXml.value(N'(/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="Sub"]/Value)[1]','uniqueidentifier') AS TheID
FROM Casted
WHERE TheXml.exist(N'/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="OperatorId"]/Value[text()="1001"]')=1
```

returns

```
E23DD735-DCF4-4878-8810-EAC2594C58A4
```

Try it like this to get a derived table:

```
WITH Casted AS (SELECT ID,CAST(YourXmlAsString AS XML) AS TheXml FROM @tbl AS t)
SELECT ID 
      ,pv.value(N'(Name/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Parameter_Name
      ,pv.value(N'(Value/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Parameter_Value
FROM Casted 
CROSS APPLY Casted.TheXml.nodes(N'/ParameterValues/ParameterValue') AS A(pv)
```

The result

```
ID  Parameter_Name  Parameter_Value
1   Sub             E23DD735-DCF4-4878-8810-EAC2594C58A4
1   OperatorId      1001
```